# Moodle without stylesheet

Tags: css, stylesheet, moodle

I've just installed the latest version of moodle on my server but I get the  moodle site with no styles as if it can't detect the css sheet.

During the installation process was all apparently well but once I finished I get my moodle site without styles, you can check [here](http://formacion.drones-ingenieria.es/)

If someone could help me I would appreciate it, thanks

Comment: i guess theme is not present there, please check if <moodle>/theme/clean is present.

Comment: It seems that the "clean" theme isn't installed correctly. The link to its CSS file is http://formacion.drones-ingenieria.es/theme/styles.php/clean/1463641494/all

If you call that url you'll get the information "Theme was not found, sorry." The CSS file is there though. Maybe some other files are missing? When you log in and go to http://formacion.drones-ingenieria.es/admin/ does it tell you that you need to upgrade your moodle database to install one or more themes? When you go to /theme/index.php what does it say for the current default theme?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this other post [moodle not showing CSS and theme with linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782203/moodle-not-showing-css-and-theme-with-linux-server)  That works perfectly for me.
Thank you for all.

Comment: See my comment above. [Using slash arguments - MoodleDocs](https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Using_slash_arguments)

Answer (score 0):

This might also happen if there is any error in scss files.

Check if you have missed any semi-colon at the end of any line.
Mostly the misspelled properties or values throws this error.

Turn on the theme designer mode to get to know the detailed error.

Answer (score -1):

// Got to do this //
url : `http://moodle.test/admin/settings.php?section=http`
Use slash arguments slasharguments => **uncheck the checkbox** (Default: Yes)

Comment: unchecking this will allow *webfonts* and *styles with comments* to load, but ['Slash arguments' (using PATH_INFO) is required for SCORM packages and multiple-file resources to display correctly. If your web server doesn't support 'slash arguments' and you are unable to configure it, the setting can be disabled, though it will result in things not working.](https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Using_slash_arguments), so should be other solution.